in a custom treeview form when drawing the nodes there are some artifacts between the nodes. how to remove this artifacts?
I can't figure out why there are these artifacts, and how to remove them?
in the top:
public partial class CustomFolderBrowser : Form
{
    private TreeView folderTreeView;
    private Button okButton;
    private Button cancelButton;
    private Button makeNewFolderButton;
    private BufferedLabel feedbackLabel;

    private Image expandIcon;
    private Image collapseIcon;

    public string SelectedPath { get; private set; }

then in the drawnode event:
private void FolderTreeView_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the bounds of the node
    Rectangle nodeRect = e.Node.Bounds;

    // Clear the icon area before redrawing
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);  // Clear previous drawing

    /*--------- 1. Draw expand/collapse icon ---------*/
    if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        // Calculate position for expand/collapse icon
        Point ptExpand = new Point(nodeRect.Left - 16, nodeRect.Top + (nodeRect.Height - 16) / 2); // Align vertically

        // Choose the appropriate icon
        Image expandCollapseImg = e.Node.IsExpanded ? collapseIcon : expandIcon;

        // Draw the icon (ensure it is redrawn over a clear background)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(expandCollapseImg, ptExpand);
    }

    /*--------- 2. Draw node text ---------*/
    // Get the node's font (default if none is set)
    Font nodeFont = e.Node.NodeFont ?? ((TreeView)sender).Font;

    // Set the color for the text (highlight if selected)
    Brush textBrush = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
    if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
    {
        textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, nodeRect); // Highlight background
    }

    // Draw the text
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, nodeFont, textBrush, nodeRect);
    
    // Draw focus rectangle if node is selected
    if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Focused) != 0)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds);
    }
}

this artifact happens in many of the nodes. i just show some examples.

and in here i marked the artifacts on the right with red circles

here is the full code.  a bit long so i put it in the bottom.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomFolder
{
    public partial class CustomFolderBrowser : Form
    {
        private TreeView folderTreeView;
        private Button okButton;
        private Button cancelButton;
        private Button makeNewFolderButton;
        private BufferedLabel feedbackLabel;

        private Image expandIcon;
        private Image collapseIcon;

        public string SelectedPath { get; private set; }

        public CustomFolderBrowser()
        {
            InitializeComponents();

            okButton.Enabled = false;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            // Load the icons from resources (make sure these are 16x16 size)
            expandIcon = Properties.Resources.icons8_forward_8; // Right-facing arrow
            collapseIcon = Properties.Resources.icons8_expand_arrow_8; // Down-facing arrow

            // Enable owner drawing for the TreeView
            folderTreeView.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawAll;
            folderTreeView.DrawNode += FolderTreeView_DrawNode;

            this.Resize += CustomFolderBrowser_Resize;
            this.Move += CustomFolderBrowser_Move;

            LoadDrives();
        }

        private void CustomFolderBrowser_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateFeedbackLabel();
        }

        private void CustomFolderBrowser_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateFeedbackLabel();
        }

        private void UpdateFeedbackLabel()
        {
            // Code to update move and resize feedback, if necessary
        }

        private void InitializeComponents()
        {
            this.Text = "Select Folder";
            this.Size = new Size(332, 349);

            folderTreeView = new DoubleBufferedTreeView
            {
                Size = new Size(290, 208),
                Location = new Point(12, 55)
            };

            folderTreeView.AfterSelect += FolderTreeView_AfterSelect;
            folderTreeView.BeforeExpand += FolderTreeView_BeforeExpand;

            okButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "Ok",
                Size = new Size(75, 23),
                Location = new Point(147, 280)
            };
            okButton.Click += OkButton_Click;

            cancelButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "Cancel",
                Size = new Size(75, 23),
                Location = new Point(227, 280)
            };
            cancelButton.Click += (s, e) => this.Close();

            makeNewFolderButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "Make New Folder",
                Size = new Size(120, 23),
                Location = new Point(12, 280)
            };

            feedbackLabel = new BufferedLabel
            {
                Text = string.Empty,
                ForeColor = Color.Red,
                Size = new Size(300, 20),
                Location = new Point(12, 25)
            };

            Controls.Add(folderTreeView);
            Controls.Add(feedbackLabel);
            Controls.Add(okButton);
            Controls.Add(cancelButton);
            Controls.Add(makeNewFolderButton);
        }

        private void LoadDrives()
        {
            foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(drive.Name) { Tag = drive.RootDirectory.FullName };
                folderTreeView.Nodes.Add(node);
                node.Nodes.Add("Loading..."); // Placeholder for expandable drives
            }

            feedbackLabel.Select();
        }

        private void FolderTreeView_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode node = e.Node;
            if (node.Nodes[0].Text == "Loading...")
            {
                node.Nodes.Clear();
                LoadSubDirectories(node);
            }
        }

        private void LoadSubDirectories(TreeNode node)
        {
            string path = (string)node.Tag;
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                    TreeNode subNode = new TreeNode(directory.Name) { Tag = directory.FullName };
                    node.Nodes.Add(subNode);
                    subNode.Nodes.Add("Loading...");
                    okButton.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                feedbackLabel.Text = "Access Denied to folder.";
                okButton.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void FolderTreeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedPath = (string)e.Node.Tag;
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(selectedPath);
            try
            {
                var subDirs = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();
                feedbackLabel.Text = string.Empty;
                SelectedPath = selectedPath;
                okButton.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                feedbackLabel.Text = "Folder Access Denied.";
                okButton.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void FolderTreeView_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the bounds of the node
            Rectangle nodeRect = e.Node.Bounds;

            // Clear the icon area before redrawing
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);  // Clear previous drawing

            /*--------- 1. Draw expand/collapse icon ---------*/
            if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                // Calculate position for expand/collapse icon
                Point ptExpand = new Point(nodeRect.Left - 16, nodeRect.Top + (nodeRect.Height - 16) / 2); // Align vertically

                // Choose the appropriate icon
                Image expandCollapseImg = e.Node.IsExpanded ? collapseIcon : expandIcon;

                // Draw the icon (ensure it is redrawn over a clear background)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(expandCollapseImg, ptExpand);
            }

            /*--------- 2. Draw node text ---------*/
            // Get the node's font (default if none is set)
            Font nodeFont = e.Node.NodeFont ?? ((TreeView)sender).Font;

            // Set the color for the text (highlight if selected)
            Brush textBrush = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
            if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
            {
                textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, nodeRect); // Highlight background
            }

            // Draw the text
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, nodeFont, textBrush, nodeRect);

            // Draw focus rectangle if node is selected
            if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Focused) != 0)
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds);
            }
        }

        private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedPath))
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateTreeView()
        {
            folderTreeView.BeginUpdate();
            try
            {
                // Perform updates to the TreeView here
            }
            finally
            {
                folderTreeView.EndUpdate();
            }
        }

        public class BufferedLabel : Label
        {
            public BufferedLabel()
            {
                this.DoubleBuffered = true;
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            }
        }

        public class DoubleBufferedTreeView : TreeView
        {
            public DoubleBufferedTreeView()
            {
                // Enable double buffering
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                this.UpdateStyles();
            }

            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            {
                // Suppress background erase to reduce flickering
                if (m.Msg == 0x0014) // WM_ERASEBKGND
                    return;

                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }
        }
    }
}


In msdn example the bounds to clear are calculated using NodeBounds() helper method. I guess you need to do something similar to clear text properly before drawing a new one.

According to the MSDN link above this has to do with the Tag value. Instead of using the tag, you could also create your own node type: class DataTreeNode<TData> : TreeNode with this property: public TData Data { get; set; }.

Hard to come up with a theory from incomplete code.  Consider that it is actually unpainted, letting the content of the window behind the form peek through.  Why the treeview doesn't clear its background before firing the events is hard to guess.

@HansPassant you right i added also the full code to my question.  it might help.  thanks.

The problem is at the bottom of the code, WM_ERASEBKGND is in fact important.

You can enable the explorer style as an alternative. You'll get the same result except that the arrows blue color is a hover effect. Also, I'm not sure whether this is the right way to set the treeview DoubleBuffered if this is a .NET Framework app. See this answer for example about that.

.NET Framework TreeView.DoubleBuffered vs. .NET TreeView.DoubleBuffered

Noting Hans' comment but leaving WM_ERASEBKGND disabled as you have it, when I ran your code the first thing I noticed was text being cut off so I was looking carefully at e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, nodeFont, textBrush, nodeRect);
In some cases, I noticed it being called with nodeRect.Width and nodeRect.Height being both zero values, so I added this block at the start and am getting hits.
private void FolderTreeView_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node is null || e.Bounds.Width == 0 || e.Bounds.Height == 0)
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
        base.OnDrawNode(e);
        return;
    }
    // Get the bounds of the node
    Rectangle nodeRect = e.Node.Bounds;
   ...
}

I also saw some discrepancies between values I obtained using MeasureString and the values in nodeRect. When I made the adjustment shown, the text was no longer truncated.
{
    .
    .
    .

    // Draw the text
    SizeF stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(
                        e.Node.Text,
                        e.Node.NodeFont ?? folderTreeView.Font);
    int
            stringWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(e.Graphics.MeasureString(
                        e.Node.Text,
                        e.Node.NodeFont ?? folderTreeView.Font
                        ).Width)),
            stringHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(e.Graphics.MeasureString(
                        e.Node.Text,
                        e.Node.NodeFont ?? folderTreeView.Font
                        ).Height));
    switch (e.Node.Text)
    {
        case string s when s.Contains("Program Files"):
            Debug.Assert(nodeRect.Width >= stringWidth, $"Should be >= {stringWidth} Is {nodeRect.Width}" );
            Debug.Assert(nodeRect.Height >= stringHeight, $"Should be >= {stringHeight} Is {nodeRect.Height}" );
            break;
    }
    nodeRect.Width = stringWidth;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, nodeFont, textBrush, nodeRect);



What I didn't see are the specific artifacts you show. I couldn't reproduce that here, and the above items wouldn't appear to be something that would cause them. They might be something worth looking into even so...

working.  just a side question.  is there a way to prevent from the treeview to flicker when the mouse cursor is hover/over the nodes ?  i tried double buffer but it's not working not fixed it.  you can see it in my full code in my question.  thank you.

When I set CustomFolderBrowser.DoubleBuffered to true it seems to stop the flickering. Clone

weird. just the very first root has a little flicker.... When you say i tried double buffer did yo do that in the TreeView or the form that contains it?
